# Unable to start Genymotion and Virtual device version don't match, getting network error issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I'm Using **Genymotion Emulator** on android development, initially i worked on android studio emulator. Just I started working genymotion for  debugging  and testing android application. I download genymotion .exe file **"genymotion-2.12.0-vbox.exe"** 
1. I installed Genymotion and virtual device in my windows laptop. 
2. after installation successfully, i cant add emulator and showing network error etc
3. below i uploaded screen shots. [image]

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find the answer to the "Network Error" issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download virtualbox with newest version from https://www.virtualbox.org/  and reinstall virtualbox.